# Passing methods on React Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I was changing around a slideshow that was on w3s schools and turning it into a react component. I changed all the functions into methods on the class, and made it so the initial state was the first slide. Then when you click the buttons or the dots, for it to change with setState. However, these functions are not coming up in the browser. Even when I console.log(func_name) it says undefined. I've changed the images so it can be tested.

I also know when the methods do appear ill have to change `onClick='func_name'` to `onClick={this.func_name}`

1. React Component

```
import React from 'react';
import RightArrow from './rightarrow.jsx'
import LeftArrow from './leftarrow.jsx'

export default class Slideshow extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      slideCount: 0
    }
    this.nextSlide = this.nextSlide.bind(this);
    this.previousSlide = this.previousSlide.bind(this);
    this.showSlides = this.showSlides.bind(this);
  }

  nextSlide() {
    this.setState({
      slideCount: this.state.slideCount + 1
    })
  }

  previousSlide() {
    this.setState({
      slideCount: this.state.slideCount - 1
    })
  }

  showSlides(n) {
    let slideCount = 0;
    const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      this.setState({
        slideCount: 0
      })
    }
    if (n < slides.length) {
      this.setState({
        slideCount: 0
      })
      slideCount = slides.length - 1
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideCount].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideCount].className = "active";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="slideshow-container">
          <div className="mySlides fade">
            <div className="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/06/09/06/07/barbecue-123668_1280.jpg" className="slide-img" />
            <div className="text">Caption Text</div>
          </div>

          <div className="mySlides fade">
            <div className="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/06/18/29/meat-1440105_1280.jpg" className="slide-img" />
            <div className="text">Caption Two</div>
          </div>

          <div className="mySlides fade">
            <div className="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/08/14/14/21/shish-kebab-417994_1280.jpg" className="slide-img" />
            <div className="text">Caption Three</div>
          </div>

          <LeftArrow />
          <RightArrow />
        </div>
        <br />

        <div className="slideshow-dot">

          <span className="dot" onClick='currentSlide(1)'></span>
          <span className="dot" onClick='currentSlide(2)'></span>
          <span className="dot" onClick='currentSlide(3)'></span>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the accompanying CSS

```
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Slide Images */

.slide-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.dot-control {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Comment: Next time, please indent your code.

Comment: Where is the onClick? is should be on the LeftArrow/RightArrow components. You are not passing onClick

Comment: `<span className="dot" onClick='() => this.showSlides(1)'></span>`
Is this work?

Answer (score 2):

To call meyhod of component You should use `this` construction `onClick={() => this.yourFunction('yourParametr')}` or without arguments `onClick={this.yourFunction}`

Answer (score 1):

Update your code with following.

You need to attach method handlers to the arrow components.

```
<div className="slideshow-dot"> <span className="dot" onClick='showSlide(1)'></span> <span className="dot" onClick='currentSlide(2)'></span> <span className="dot" onClick='showSlide(3)'></span> </div>
```